# Delete the second record where a user has two records

Tags: mysql, subquery, delete

I have a simple database scheme, which due to previously being badly set up has numerous duplicate records.

### record_table

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| id  | subid  | catid  | start_date | end_date          |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |  1     | 1      | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31        |
| 2   |  1     | 1      | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31        |
| 3   |  2     | 1      | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31        |
| 4   |  2     | 1      | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31        |
| 5   |  3     | 1      | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31        |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to delete records 2 and 4, because there is already a record for that subid/catid combo that covers the same dates.

I want to be able to do:

```
DELETE from record_table WHERE catid='1' AND 
    start_date<='2015-02-13' AND 
    end_date>='2015-02-13' AND 
    [the user has two records for the previous conditions]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

- Create a TempTable(record_table_keep) with minimum `id` for every `subid,catid` combination
- Perform a DELETE JOIN between `record_table` and `record_table_keep` using `LEFT JOIN`
- Only delete records from `record_table` whose id is not in `record_table_keep`

## Proposed Query

```
CREATE TABLE record_table_keep
SELECT id,subid,catid FROM record_table WHERE 0=1;
ALTER TABLE record_table_keep ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
INSERT INTO record_table_keep (id,subid,catid)
SELECT MIN(id) id,subid,catid FROM record_table GROUP BY subid,catid;
DELETE A.* FROM record_table A
LEFT JOIN record_table_keep B USING (id)
WHERE B.id IS NULL;
DROP TABLE record_table_keep;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score -3):

```
DELETE FROM record_table a
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT subid
                 FROM record_table b
                WHERE a.subid= b.subid
                  AND a.id < b.id )
```

Comment: I get 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a WHERE EXISTS(
 SELECT subid
 FROM record_table b
 WHERE a.subid= b.subid
 AND a' at line 2